# How can I specify drawing text with FFMPEG while generating thumbnails for the entire video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm successfully using ffmpeg via PHP to capture thumbnails every 15 seconds from our videos, but I need to add a copyright notice to each of them.  I've researched enough to find that it can be done, and what the arguments are to do it, but I can't figure out the syntax to use it without getting various errors from ffmpeg depending on where/how I put it in the command line.

I was told to provide the output I'm getting, so it's included below, but what I need help with is the correct *syntax* to specify what I need with the FFMPEG command.

**a.) Working FFMPEG command:**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mp4 -vf "thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/15" D:\video_%05d.jpg
```

**b.) Desired arguments to add to the working command above:**

```
"drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile='c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text=\'My Copyright Text\':x=(w-text_w)/2:0"
```

How to I correctly include the arguments shown in **b.** with the command in **a.**?

**c.) Flavor of what I've tried:**
I've tried putting **b.** in several places such as below, but all yield errors similar in some fashion or other to **e.** below.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mp4 -vf "thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/15" "drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf:text='My Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0" D:\video_%05d.jpg
```

**e.) Sample Output/error**

```
C:\>ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mp4 -vf "thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/15 drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=Dc:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0" D:\captures\video_%05d.jpg -loglevel error
[fps @ 0000000004fec000] Unable to parse option value "1/15 drawtext=fontsize=20" as video rate
[Parsed_fps_2 @ 0000000005000980] Option 'box' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000509ba40] Error initializing filter 'fps' with args '1/15 drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text=CMy Copyright Text:x=(w-text_w)/2:0'
Error opening filters!

C:\>ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mp4 -vf "thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/15", "drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0" D:\captures\video_%05d.jpg -loglevel error
[NULL @ 0000000005053140] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0'
drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0: Invalid argument

C:\>ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mp4 -vf "thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/15"  D:\captures\video_%05d.jpg "drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0" -loglevel error
[NULL @ 0000000004fc49c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0'
drawtext=fontsize=20:box=1:fontfile=c:\windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='CMy Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0: Invalid argument
```

***Typical* Console Output**

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel verbose -i d:\myvideo.mp4 -vf "thumbnail, scale=640:480, fps=1/15 drawtext=fontsize=30:box=1:fontfile=c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text='My Copyright Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:0" D:\captures\captured_%05d.jpg
ffmpeg version N-73975-gda8b70b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 52.100 / 56. 52.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 27.100 /  5. 27.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'd:\myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2013-12-18 21:48:29
    encoder         : Encoded by LearningCORE
  Duration: 00:29:09.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1573 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-18 21:48:29
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Baseline), 3 reference frames (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1436 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-17 21:37:07
      handler_name    : vide
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 12 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-18 21:37:13
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 56 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-18 21:37:14
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 640x480, 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-18 21:48:43
      handler_name    : bc200_00.srt:hdlr=sbtl:lang=en:group=2:delay=0 - Imported with GPAC 0.5.0-rev4065
[Parsed_thumbnail_0 @ 0000000004fa6780] batch size: 100 frames
[Parsed_scale_1 @ 0000000004fc18c0] w:640 h:480 flags:'0x4' interl:0
[fps @ 0000000004fac9a0] Unable to parse option value "1/15 drawtext=fontsize=30" as video rate
[Parsed_fps_2 @ 0000000004fc2b80] Option 'box' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000505c0a0] Error initializing filter 'fps' with args '1/15 drawtext=fontsize=30:box=1:fontfile=c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:text=My Copyright Text:x=(w-text_w)/2:0'
[Parsed_fps_2 @ 0000000004fc2b80] 0 frames in, 0 frames out; 0 frames dropped, 0 frames duplicated.
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Heree's a sample..but its' the error at the end of all of them that consistently about the syntax of the command.  Clearly i'm not specifying it correctly.  The FFMPEG reads/writes perfectly except when I incorrectly supply the copyright/text argument in the command line

Comment: There should be a single set of quotes enclosing all filters with a comma after `1/15` followed by the drawtext filters in your 'c' command.

Comment: @Mulvya THANK-you...that's almost all I needed....the only problem I have now is how to specify the full path to the font.  With forward/and backward slashes, I'm seeing `Could not load font "c": cannot open resource`

Comment: @Mulvya - That was the ticket, and further research says that a colon can't be specifed in the fontifle path.  PLEASE put post your answer so that I can accept it....I've been searching/asking this question for days, and have had no help at all until now. :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of filters applied to a single video stream in sequence should be enclosed in a single set of quotes with a comma separating each individual filter. So, in the command shown in **c**, there should be a comma after `fps=1/15` followed by the `drawtext` filter.